# Not linear swipe over screen

Tags: java, android, c++, c

I am working on a bot-like android app (to control other apps) 
Currently I perform Taps and 2 point linear Swipes over other apps creating a service and running /system/bin/input swipe/tap command with SU access 
(this works on whatever is on top)

I want to know the way to do a 3+ point non-linear swipe.

I know it is possible by using c/c++ code and importing the library, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: "Bot-like" app? Do you mean for automation or possibly illegal control?

Comment: More like automate repetitive tasks

Comment: Just making sure which definition of "bot" you were using. :-)

Comment: @JohnnyLynch two questions: what do you mean by 3+ point non-linear swipe? And what do you mean "using c++ code and importing the library"? Are you possibly talking about JNI and native programming?

Comment: @LBes
3+ point non-linear swipe
 More than 2 point swipe i mean a curved swipe or TouchDown>TouchMove(to different x,y points)>TouchUp
Yes I am talking about JNI and native programming.

Comment: @JohnnyLynch so if I understood correctly, I have posted a piece of code that may help you out

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I base this answer on your last comment and I suppose you know how to use the JNI and I assume you want to handle all the computation based on the fingers positions with native code. That's what I understood from your comment (and question).

So you first need to recover the touch events through your Java code with something like this: (please note that I don't handle here more than 3 fingers and the possible errors associated).

```
public class MainActivity extends ... implements View.OnTouchListener
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //First compute RAW coordinates of each touch event
        float rawPosX[] = new float[3];
        float rawPosY[] = new float[3];
        int [] ids = new int[3];
        int nbFingers = event.getPointerCount() ;
        for (int i = 0; i < nbFingers; i++) {
            rawPosX[i] = //RawX of each point I assume you have that code already
            rawPosY[i] = //RawY of each point I assume you have that code already
            ids[i]  = event.getPointerId(i);
        }
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                {  
                      int index = event.getActionIndex();
                      int id = event.getPointerId(index);
                      NativeApp.addFinger(rawPosX[index], rawPosY[index], id);
                      break ;
                }  
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                {
                    int index = event.getActionIndex(); 
                    int id = event.getPointerId(index);
                    NativeApp.removeFinger(id);
                    break ;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {  
                    for (int i = 0; i < nbFingers; ++i)
                    {

                            NativeApp.updateFingerPositions(rawPosX[i], rawPosY[i], ids[i]);  

                    }
                    break ;
         }
    }
}
```

Then in your native code you should have the following functions:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Package_updateFingerPositions(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jfloat x, jfloat y, jint fingerID);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Package_addFinger(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jfloat x, jfloat y, jint fingerID);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Package_removeFinger(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint fingerID);
```

And the following vectors:

```
//This is considering you have a Vector3 class, which I often have myself. But you can easily adapt it with `std::tuple`. I use a Vector3 so as to store the x and y position 
std::vector<Vector3> fingerPositions ;
std::vector<Vector3> previousFingerPositions ;
```

I am not going to detail the addFinger() and removeFinger() functions as they are pretty easy to code. But in the update you should have something like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL  Package_updateFingerPositions(float x, float y, int fingerID){
    int position = getFingerPos(fingerID); // This returns the position of the finger with this Id in your vector storing the finger positions.
    Vector3 pos(x,y, fingerID); // To update your previousFingerPositions vector
    if(position == -1){
       return ;
    }
        //Remember to update everything first
    previousFingerPositions [position] = fingerPositions[position] ;
    fingerPositions[position] = pos ;
    if(fingerPositions.size() == 3){
        //That's what you want here.
        //You can do your computation here and use the previous positions for the computations that you need
    }

}
```

Please note: this code is not optimised at all and completely untested. There may be errors in it but that's the best I can do from a mobile device. I hope it helps you and I hope I understood your problem correctly.